# AJAX in javascript does not communicate with php mailer after SSL upgrade

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ssl

OK, so I have many quizzes which previously worked fine on my http:// website, using AJAX javascript calls to a php mailer program to send data about the quiz and mail it to the recipient.
I have upgraded the site to https:// and now none of the scripts work. The bones of the javascript are contained in the following function:

```
function postIt() {   
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "../mail/summary.php";
var params = "realname="+myName+"&rightAnswers="+correct+"&percentageScore="+percentage+"&wrongArray="+wstore+"&asked="+numq+"&mins="+minutes+"&secs="+seconds+"&deliver="+destination+"&testName="+test;
http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {   //Call a function when the state changes.
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    //alert(http.responseText);
}
}
http.send(null);
}
```

The php mailer receives the variables and mails them. Again the bones of the php are below:

```
$data1=$_GET["realname"];
$data2=$_GET["rightAnswers"];
$data3=$_GET["asked"];
$data4=$_GET["mins"];
$data5=$_GET["secs"];
$data6=$_GET["percentageScore"];
$data7=$_GET["deliver"];
$data8=$_GET["testName"];
$myWrongArray = explode(',', $_GET["wrongArray"]);

$sendTo = "results@ibchem.com".", ".$data7;
$subject = $data8." summary results for ".$data1;
```

The code is fine for http:// websites (I have tested it again on http://mypchem.com/test) but fails on https://ibchem.com/test.

My level of understanding is pushed to the limit as I can code (average) in javascript, html, css, php etc. but have no idea how to solve this problem.

Any help please?

Charco

Comment: It the page the script is running on http or https and are there any console messages?

Comment: All the relevant files are in folders in https://ibchem.com/test. The htm files are in https://ibchem.com/test/htm/, the javascript file is in https://ibchem.com/test/js/ and the php mailer file is in https://ibchem.com/test/mail/

Comment: I do not know how to view console messages (or what they are!)

Comment: press F12 and click Console

Comment: And my question was: Is YOUR site http or https. I know the TARGET sites are https

Comment: Checked the console - returns nothing, just blank screen. MY site is https://ibchem.com and all of the files are in folders under https://ibchem.com/test/ - it seems that SO is removing the "https://" from my posts ...

Comment: How to recreate the issue, step by step?

Comment: To replicate the issue open https://ibchem.com/test/htm/237-aufbau.htm you will need username (guest) and password (guest). This is a test in which you can fill in the email address, although this also gets sent to my email. When the test is finished it automatically calls the function shown above to send the results of the test to a php file for mailing.

Comment: Please scrub all of the above! It turns out that my web server had flagged all output from the php file as spam! I'm very sorry for wasting anyone's time. It took them (ipowerweb) two days to find out the problem was the server side.